# Why doesn't collections.Counter or .count() give correct answer here?

Tags: python

The problem is given an input find out how many 1 are there in the input.
eg. i/p 1011 then o/p 3

I have used collections.Counter as well as .count('1') to find number of 1's but it gives 1 less count. What is the reason?

```py
class Solution(object):
    def hammingWeight(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        s = str(n)
        dic = collections.Counter(s)
        return dic['1']
```

I/P: 1011
O/P: 2
Expected O/P: 3

Comment: It works for me. tested in python 3.7.4

Comment: Are you looking for `bin(n)`?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

Comment: `Solution().hammingWeight(1011) >>> 3`

Comment: If your problem statement is right, I see nothing wrong in this code. Gives expected result in python 3.7.0

Comment: Thank you guys. It seems that the code does not work on Leetcode console for some reason.